# Capture value from shell script and use it in Python without using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, python-2.3

I have a python script which requires a value from a shell script.

Following is the shell script (a.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
return_value(){
  value=$(///some unix command)
  echo "$value"
}

return_value
```

Following is the python script:

```
Import subprocess
answer = Subprocess.call([‘./a.sh’])
print("the answer is %s % answer")
```

But its not working.The error is:

`ImportError : No module named subprocess`

I guess my verison (Python 2.3.4) is pretty old. Is there any substitute for `subprocess` that can be applied in this case??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`commands`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) module for py2.3.4, note that this module has been deprecated since py2.6:

Use [`commands.getoutput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#commands.getoutput):

```
import commands
answer = commands.getoutput('./a.sh')
```

Comment: It worked !!!! How do you think of this? I know our team needs to update our python version but Thanks a lot !